# How was God created?

Tags: nature-of-god

We're assuming God created everything.

Who created God?

Can any doctrine answer this question?

Comment: This doesn't meet quality standards, not because of length but because of content. The question needs to be scoped further, say, from a specific denominational or doctrinal perspective or "what does the bible say". See the [about] page.

Answer (score 8):

According to almost all branches of Christianty<sup>1</sup>, God was never created, he has always existed. And always will exist. He is eternal. Deuteronomy 33:27 specifically identifies God as eternal, but there are numerous passages that point out this aspect of his nature. In fact the very way in which he introduces himself gives us a clue about this.

> **[Exodus 3:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+3:14&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>14</sup>  God said to Moses, “I am who I am.” And he said, “Say this to the people of Israel, ‘I am has sent me to you.’”

Almost every major Creed in Christian history has some statement about this aspect of God. For example the Athanasian Creede, a very old and widely used one identifies Christian believe about God in this way:

> But the Godhead of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit is all one, the glory equal, the majesty **coeternal.**

A more modern day statement of faith, the Westminster Confession of Faith states it this way:

> The Father is of none, neither **begotten nor proceeding** […]

The person of God is the only truely eternal thing, existing from eternity past. While the souls of people will go on existing for eterinty, they were created. In fact ALL other things outside of the being of God were created and are being held together by God himself (though the person of Christ).

> **[Colossians 1:16-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=col%201:16-17&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>16</sup>  For **by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him**. <sup>17</sup>  And he is before all things, and in him all things hold together.

<sub>1. The minior exception are a couple sects such as Mormonism that have beliefs about him existing in some other prior form before he became god.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> 1Ti 1:17  Now unto the King eternal, immortal, invisible, the only wise God, be honour and glory for ever and ever. Amen.
>
> Gen 1:1  In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
>
> 1Jn 5:20  And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life.

God is eternal which means he exists before the creation of time and will exist after time ends. He offers us eternal life in Christ Jesus the ability to transcend our mortal lives and not experience eternal death and torture.